# how to get nice reports easily from poker tracker 4?

Tags: texas-hold-em, no-limit, pokertracker

my students and i are using pt4 at a couple of online casinos.

we would like to have reports that we can easily convert to html so we can all see how we are doing.

but the only way to get reports out of pt4 involves clicking and saving a bunch of things like .csv files or .png files, so it's sorta painful.

they do not expose any api, so i am stuck unless someone knows how to grep around the their database.

any pointers will be appreciated.

thanks

edit in response to Notorious Pet0: all of the .csv data that i want is probably already in some pt4 report that i can export. the problem is more like taking a few of these, removing a few rows and columns and and stuffing them in some html page automagically every month so one could see some progress. otherwise it's very time consuming.

Comment: as *Notorious Pet0 pointed out, Pokertracker stores all information in a _postgreSQL_ database, in my system this is stored in `C:/postgreSQL/*`. You don't need an API to work with this, merely `PHP and their pg_x` family of functions to query directly the relevant information and produce HTML. Furthermore, you could use [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org) to break down the data PT4 is working on. Although i sense this is harder than it looks since if reports don't _give away_ the queries used for this, that means you should find them. If i ever had to do such thing, that would be my approach.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get it out of the PT client is through their export command.  It gives you a CSV file which you should be able to import to excel and play with the data, make graphs, whatever.

I don't know of any programs that are specifically made for PT but it's just a pgSQL database running on your system which makes it actually easier than a program using proprietary storage methods you would have to figure out how to access, query, and parse results.

It's also good that the DB is running on your local system as opposed to the software companies server because you have root access to all the data.

What kind of data are you looking to get out of it and maybe I can write some queries for you.   I am an expert with SQL, it's my day job.  :)

Comment: Had a look at your edit.   Can you go here inceptz.com and leave your addy? i can try to create some kind of webform where you upload the csv but ill need the details on what you actually want.  Just put PT4SQL as the comments when you leave your addy.  Thanks :)